# I can't merge branches. Conflicts in Git. MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, git, merge

I'm trying merge my branches, but I get the error **merge completed with conflict**
http://prntscr.com/936x6n (as u see even with **git gui** i can't)

I tried skip database. So i added to .gitignore ***.mdf*** and **.ldf**, but still nothing. I can't merge branches. What should I do?

Comment: You should post the text of the output in your question directly, not as a external link to an image.

Comment: Edited, however its only "merge completed with conflict" that's why i pasted screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore some files during the merge, Git attributes using merge strategies for specific files could help. Here is an example that the specifies files stay at whatever version you originally had.

1. create .gitattributes in your repo and edit:
    merge=ours
    merge=ours
   ...
2. And then define a dummy ours merge strategy with:
   $ git config --global merge.ours.driver true

Comment: AutoMoint/AutoMonit/App_Data/Pojazdy.mdf merge=ours 

AutoMoint/AutoMonit/App_Data/Pojazdy_log.ldf merge=ours